# How to set the state of a Google Visualization Motion Chart?

Tags: java, gwt, google-visualization

I'm using GWT and the [Google Chart Tools (aka Visualization) 1.1 Library](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted) of the [Google API Libraries for GWT](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/).

I want to display a Motion Chart and to set the state as possible in [Javascript](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/motionchart.html#Motion_Chart_initial_state).

Has someone an idea how to set the state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is slightly modified MotionChart from GWT-Getting Started page with data from Javascript documentation. I Didn't test it so I'm not sure if the code works.

```
public class SimpleViz implements EntryPoint {
              public void onModuleLoad() {
                // Create a callback to be called when the visualization API
                // has been loaded.
                Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                    Panel panel = RootPanel.get();

                    MotionChart chart = new MotionChart(createTable(), createOptions());

                    panel.add(chart);
                  }
                };
                VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, MotionChart.PACKAGE);
              }

              private Options createOptions() {
                Options options = Options.create();
                options.setWidth(600);
                options.setHeight(300);
                options.setTitle("My Motion Chart");

                //  Passing JSON state with escaped double quotes to options class. 
                options.setState("{\"orderedByY\":false,\"showTrails\":true,\"dimensions\":{\"iconDimensions\":[\"dim0\"]},\"yAxisOption\":\"3\",\"xZoomedIn\":false,\"time\":\"1988-04-16\",\"yZoomedIn\":false,\"xAxisOption\":\"2\",\"yZoomedDataMin\":150,\"yZoomedDataMax\":617,\"xZoomedDataMin\":300,\"uniColorForNonSelected\":false,\"xLambda\":1,\"playDuration\":15000,\"yLambda\":1,\"duration\":{\"timeUnit\":\"D\",\"multiplier\":1},\"iconType\":\"BUBBLE\",\"iconKeySettings\":[{\"trailStart\":\"1988\",\"key\":{\"dim0\":\"Apples\"}},{\"trailStart\":\"1988\",\"key\":{\"dim0\":\"Oranges\"}},{\"trailStart\":\"1988\",\"key\":{\"dim0\":\"Bananas\"}}],\"colorOption\":\"2\",\"xZoomedDataMax\":1200,\"nonSelectedAlpha\":0.4,\"orderedByX\":false,\"sizeOption\":\"_UNISIZE\"}");
                return options;
              }

              private AbstractDataTable createTable() {
                DataTable data = DataTable.create();
                    data.addColumn('string', 'Fruit');
                    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
                    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
                    data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
                    data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
                data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Fruit");
                data.addColumn(ColumnType.DATE, "Date");
                data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Sales");
                data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Expenses");
                data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Location");
                data.addRows(6);
                 data.setValue(0, 0, "Apples");
                data.setValue(0, 1, new Date (1988,0,1));
                data.setValue(0, 2, 1000);
                data.setValue(0, 3, 300);
                data.setValue(0, 4, "East");
                 data.setValue(1, 0, "Oranges");
                data.setValue(1, 1, new Date (1988,0,1));
                data.setValue(1, 2, 1150);
                data.setValue(1, 3, 200);
                data.setValue(1, 4, "West");
                 data.setValue(2, 0, "Bananas");
                data.setValue(2, 1, new Date (1988,0,1));
                data.setValue(2, 2, 300);
                data.setValue(2, 3, 250);
                data.setValue(2, 4, "West");
                 data.setValue(3, 0, "Apples");
                data.setValue(3, 1, new Date (1989,6,1));
                data.setValue(3, 2, 1200);
                data.setValue(3, 3, 400);
                data.setValue(3, 4, "East");
                 data.setValue(4, 0, "Oranges");
                data.setValue(4, 1, new Date (1989,6,1));
                data.setValue(4, 2, 750);
                data.setValue(4, 3, 150);
                data.setValue(4, 4, "West");
                 data.setValue(5, 0, "Bananas");
                data.setValue(5, 1, new Date (1989,6,1));
                data.setValue(5, 2, 788);
                data.setValue(5, 3, 617);
                data.setValue(5, 4, "West");
                return data;
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question. In the docs you referenced, there is section for setting the state.

Essentially, you have to open up the MotionChart visualization you have already populated, manipulate the entities/options you want to show up by default, and then grab the state field from GWT controls for the chart.

http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/motionchart.html#Motion_Chart_initial_state

From there, you can set the options via normal routine.

Comment: This manipulation is for Javascript, I am developing with Java.

Answer (score -1):

1. first you create your chart(s) & create the datatables that feed them - with whatever options you need for your particular application.
2. then you create the rows & columns using google's .addRow() and .addColumn() methods.
3. populate the table(s) and render your initial images using the .draw() method
4. lastly you'll need a method by which you can update the image(s).
   I created two custom functions: one to get the data via an ajax call, and the other to manipulate the data in the existing tables and request an additional .draw() periodically.

You can see a working demo and a quick tutorial here  -- http://www.logicwizards.net/monitor-lamp-servers-wbash-php5/

I hope it helps...

Comment: I am developing with Java, this is a Javascript example.